# split return data from old way ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i have page that do add new record by old way ajax, this code was add new record and return the error or done result message , how can i print the message on div and print result on other div. i try but some one tell me to use JOSN, how can i do that

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
});
$("#closeerr").live('click', function() {
    $("#gadget").hide();
});

       var HttPRequest = false;

       function doCallAjax(Mode,Page,ID) {
          HttPRequest = false;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
             HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
             if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
                HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
             }
          } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
             try {
                HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
             } catch (e) {
                try {
                   HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
             }
          } 

          if (!HttPRequest) {
             alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
             return false;
          }

          var url = 'AjaxItemsGroupsRecord.php';
          var pmeters = "titems_groups_GroupName=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("items_groups_GroupName").value) +
                        "&titems_groups_sys_type_ID=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("items_groups_sys_type_ID").value ) +
                        '&myPage='+Page +
                        "&tID=" + ID +
                        "&tMode=" + Mode;

            HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);

            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            HttPRequest.send(pmeters);


            HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {

                 if(HttPRequest.readyState == 3)  // Loading Request
                  {
                   document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "looding";
                  }

                 if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
                  {
                   document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;
                  }

            }

       }
    </script>
```

Comment: You should look into jQuery and the `ajax()` method. It would be much tidier than you have here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Basically handles all the HttpRequest bits for you so you can focus on the more important aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If jQuery is an option...** As mentioned in my comment I'd recommend you try out jQuery http://jquery.com/ as you look to be fairly new to JavaScript.
It makes AJAX requests a lot simpler and you don't have to worry about making `XMLHttpRequest` work cross browser.

For making an actual AJAX request see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Now if you want to use JSON you need to convert the data to return in your PHP script.
This is really easy, you just pass the data in `json_encode()` and it will convert the data to a JSON string. You then just echo it out so that it's returned to the AJAX request.

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now if you've setup your AJAX request to expect a JSON response then you can use the data that comes back. So something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'request.php',    // the php you want to call
    dataType: 'json'       // the type of data being returned
}).done(function(json) {
    // you now have a json object
});
```

**If you can only use native JavaScript...**
If you can't use jQuery then it roughly works the same way. You'd have the code in your example for the AJAX request. You'd still use `json_encode()` in the PHP. The only difference is when the data comes back you'd need to parse it like so:

```
JSON.parse(json);
```

For more info on this last bit checkout: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)